# find by more than one attribute in an entity

Tags: sql, magicalrecord

I want to perform the exact sql query:

```
select * from table where field1 = 'x' or field2 = 'x' or field3 = 'x'
```

So far, I can only fetch one field in the entity:

```
NSArray *products = [Product MR_findByAttribute:@"id" withValue:categoryID];
```

Let's say I want to fetch `id` and `name` fields for categoryID, how can I do that in MagicalRecord?

I can do that by:

```
NSArray *productsByID = [Product MR_findByAttribute:@"id" withValue:categoryID];
NSArray *productsByName = [Product MR_findByAttribute:@"name" withValue:categoryID];
```

Isn't there a one line solution instead? because when dealing with a lot of fields, that will become a bit complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Use NSPredicate. For example

```
[Contact MR_findAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@ or %K contains[cd] %@", @"name", @"jo", @"surname", @"jo"];
```

Where Contact is an entity, %K is placeholder for key (attribute of entity), %@ placeholder for search value.

this predicate used to find any contact which name or surname contains jo.

For you solution

```
select * from table where field1 = 'x' or field2 = 'x' or field3 = 'x'

[Product MR_findAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@ OR %K == %@ OR %K == %@", @"field1", @"x", @"field2", @"x", @"field3", @"x"];
```